# Best way to handle imbalanced dataset for multi-class classification in Auto-Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I'm using Auto-Sklearn and have a dataset with 42 classes that are heavily imbalanced. What is the best way to handle this imbalance? As far as I know, two approaches to handle imbalanced data within machine learning exist. Either using a resampling mechanism such as over- or under-sampling (or a combination of both) or to solve it on an algorithmic-level by choosing an inductive bias that would require in-depth knowledge about the algorithms used within Auto-Sklearn. I'm not quite sure on how to handle this problem. Is it anyhow possible to solve the imbalance directly within Auto-Sklearn or do I need to use resampling strategies as offered by e.g. imbalanced-learn? Which evaluation metric should be used after the models have been computed? The roc_auc_score for multiple classes is available since sklearn==0.22.1. However, Auto-Sklearn only supports sklearn up to version 0.21.3. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The other method is to set weights for classes according to their size. Effort is very little and it seems to work fine. I was looking for setting weights in auto-sklearn and this is what I have found:

https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/113

For example in scikit svm you have parameter 'class_weight':

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

One way that has worked for me in the past to handle highly imbalanced datasets is Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique (SMOTE). Here is the paper for better understanding:

[SMOTE Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf)

This works by synthetically oversampling the minority class or classes for that matter. To quote the paper:

> The minority class is over-sampled by taking each minority class
>   sample and introducing synthetic examples along the line segments
>   joining any/all of the k minority class nearest neighbors. Depending
>   upon the amount of over-sampling required, neighbors from the k
>   nearest neighbors are randomly chosen.

This then will move closer towards balancing out your dataset. There is an implementation of SMOTE in the [imblearn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package in python.

Here is a good read about [different oversampling algorithms](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/over-sampling/plot_comparison_over_sampling.html#more-advanced-over-sampling-using-adasyn-and-smote). It includes oversampling using [ADASYN](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN.html) as well as [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful! Did you also use SMOTE before training a classifier with Auto-Sklearn or did you use another ML pipeline? And do you know by any chance which metric could potentially be used other than the roc_auc_score? All the papers I had a look in so far considered the roc_auc_score but unfortunately this can't be used at the moment within auto-sklearn. The amount of different metrics and sampling strategies is overwhelming for a newbie. :D

Comment: @MoDo Thank you :) I used SMOTE before training a classifier with a different ML pipeline. 

As for the metric, I'm not fully certain because I may have used other metrics that suited my use case at the time more than the `roc_auc_score`. I can't seem to recall unfortunately.  I fully understand that the number of different metrics and sampling strategies is overwhelming. Once you start doing this every single day, it becomes a lot easier, just like everything else :)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested and as an addition to the answers given, I can highly recommend the following paper:

Lemnaru, C., & Potolea, R. (2011, June). Imbalanced classification problems: systematic study, issues and best practices. In International Conference on Enterprise Information Systems (pp. 35-50). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

The authors argue that:

> In terms of solutions, since the performance is not expected to improve
>   significantly with a more sophisticated sampling strategy, more focus should be
>   allocated to algorithm related improvements, rather than to data improvements.

As e.g. the ChaLearn AutoML Challenge 2015 used the balanced accuracy, sklearn argues that it is a fitting metric for imbalanced data and Auto-Sklearn was able to compute well-fitting models, I'm going to have a try. Even without resampling, the results were much "better" (in terms of prediction quality) than just using the accuracy.